# Setting widths in a longtable not working

Tags: tables, longtable, width

I want to create a longtable that spans several pages, with column widths set to cms by me:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{seqsplit}
\usepackage[a4paper,landscape,margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|p{3,53cm}|p{1,60cm}|p{0,80cm}|p{1,11cm}|p{1,16cm}|p{0,94cm}|p{1,11cm}|p{0,96cm}|p{0,57cm}|p{1,21cm}|p{1,04cm}|p{1,32cm}|p{1,26cm}|p{0,99cm}|p{1,27cm}|p{2,71cm}|p{1,41cm}|}
\hline
\textbf{ \seqsplit{one} } & \textbf{ \seqsplit{tow} } & \textbf{ \seqsplit{three} } & \textbf{ \seqsplit{four} } & \textbf{ \seqsplit{five} } & \textbf{ \seqsplit{six} } & \textbf{ \seqsplit{seven} } & \textbf{ \seqsplit{eight} } & \textbf{ \seqsplit{nine} } & \textbf{ \seqsplit{ten} } & \textbf{ \seqsplit{eleven} } & \textbf{ \seqsplit{twelve} } & \textbf{ \seqsplit{thirteen} } & \textbf{ \seqsplit{fourteen} } & \textbf{ \seqsplit{fifteen} } & \textbf{ \seqsplit{sixteen} } & \textbf{ \seqsplit{seventeen} } \\
\hline
\endhead
\hline
\seqsplit{aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa@gmail.com} & \seqsplit{Jjjjjj} & \seqsplit{Ccccccccl} & \seqsplit{ttrrw} & \seqsplit{xxxxxxxx\ 83} & \seqsplit{ooooooo} & \seqsplit{2222\ rrrrrrr\ oo\ trr\ bbbbb\ bbbbbbb\ ttttttP\ -\ 2111\ eeeedsee\ prrr\ vvv\ ll\ eeeirrrr\ xxrrrttt} & \seqsplit{20/02/2011\ 11:39:37} & \seqsplit{0} & \seqsplit{0,00} & \seqsplit{0,00} & \seqsplit{07/07/2011\ 09:00:00} & \seqsplit{14/07/2013\ 11:00:00} & \seqsplit{700} & \seqsplit{4} & \seqsplit{xxxxooowwwaaaaaaaaapaaa/srsssssss} & \seqsplit{50,00} \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

The problem with this tex is that I have seventeen columns, and the seventeenth appears out of the landscape page. However if we add the widths of the columns, is less than 23 cms. What's going on here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You observe that the widths assigned to the columns add up to less than the width of the text block (which has width `\textwidth`), yet the table is too wide to fit into the text block. This is happening because there's also *whitespace* between the columns, in the amount of `2\tabcolsep`. The default value of `\tabcolsep` is `6pt`. Expressed in millimeters, the default amount of intercolumn whitespace comes to roughly `4.2mm`. Since you have 17 columns, this makes for *more than 7 cm* of extra horizontal space.

What to do? You can do one or both of the following: (i) reduce some of the column widths, and (ii) reduce the amount of intercolumn whitespace via a `\renewcommand` instruction, e.g., `\renewcommand\tabcolsep{4pt}`. A combination of these instructions should get you to where you want to be.

Answer (score 5):

Your column widths sum up to 23cm, converted to 654.13022pt; the text width is 788.14136pt, which is 27.7cm (A4 paper is 21cm wide and 29.7cm high in portrait mode).

However, your table is seen by TeX as 858.13022pt wide. Where does the excess come from? Let's compute

```
(858.13022-654.13022)/17 = 12
```

Indeed *every* column in a `tabular` or `longtable` is preceded and followed by a space of width `\tabcolsep`; the default value of this parameter is precisely 6pt.

You can fit your table either reducing some column width or reducing `\tabcolsep`:

```
(788.14136-654.13022)/34 = 3.9415
```

so doing

```
\begingroup\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3.9pt}
\begin{longtable}{
 |p{3,53cm}
 |p{1,60cm}
 |p{0,80cm}
 |p{1,11cm}
 |p{1,16cm}
 |p{0,94cm}
 |p{1,11cm}
 |p{0,96cm}
 |p{0,57cm}
 |p{1,21cm}
 |p{1,04cm}
 |p{1,32cm}
 |p{1,26cm}
 |p{0,99cm}
 |p{1,27cm}
 |p{2,71cm}
 |p{1,41cm}
 |}
 <table body>
 \end{longtable}\endgroup
```

you'll achieve a table width of 786.73001pt which fits in the text width.

How did I compute the table width? It's easy: I wrote a test file

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\sbox0{%
\begin{tabular}{
 |p{3,53cm}
 |p{1,60cm}
 |p{0,80cm}
 |p{1,11cm}
 |p{1,16cm}
 |p{0,94cm}
 |p{1,11cm}
 |p{0,96cm}
 |p{0,57cm}
 |p{1,21cm}
 |p{1,04cm}
 |p{1,32cm}
 |p{1,26cm}
 |p{0,99cm}
 |p{1,27cm}
 |p{2,71cm}
 |p{1,41cm}
 |}
0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 &7 &8 &9 & A & b & C & D & F & G & H
\end{tabular}}\the\wd0
\end{document}
```

The produced PDF file has

> 858.13022pt

If I add `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3.9pt}` before the `\sbox` command I get the value

> 786.73001pt

In the document you'll add `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` as shown in order not to make the setting of `\tabcolsep` the same across the document.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, very detailed, I appreciate it.